# javascript regex validate years in range

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input field for year and I need a regex for validation it.
I have such code: `^([12]\d)?(\d\d)$`.
But I want allow to validate only years in certain range (1990-2010, for example). How can I do it?

Edit. range must be 1950-2050

Comment: Don't say `for example`. Regex is all about preciseness. Give what you want to match exactly. This is to prevent questions like `how to change this regex to match -another- x-y range`

Comment: Why do you need a regex at all? This sounds like a simple comparison to me.

Comment: don't you think you should use dropdown for selecting an year and populate it from server side according to required range.

Comment: I created this javascript lib to validate year ranges: https://github.com/jonschlinkert/is-valid-year. hope it's useful

Comment: As others have suggested, it might be better to isolate the year in the regex using groups and validate its range separately. Eg, say the string to validate is something like "ABC1990XYZ", then make regex like `r"ABC(?P<year>\d{4})XYZ"` (Python syntax). Then verify the regex match and get the "year" group value and do additional if check for the year range.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

1990 - 2010:

```
/^(199\d|200\d|2010)$/
```

1950 - 2050:

```
/^(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050)$/
```

Other examples:

1945 - 2013:

```
/^(194[5-9]|19[5-9]\d|200\d|201[0-3])$/
```

1812 - 3048:

```
/^(181[2-9]|18[2-9]\d|19\d\d|2\d{3}|30[0-3]\d|304[0-8])$/
```

Basically, you need to split your range into easy "regexable" chunks:

```
1812-3048: 1812-1819 + 1820-1899 + 1900-1999 + 2000-2999 + 3000-3039 + 3040-3048
    regex: 181[2-9]    18[2-9]\d   19\d\d      2\d{3}      30[0-3]\d   304[0-8]
```

Comment: Wonderful examples! Thanx a lot!

Comment: Your first regex doesn't work for the OP's requirements. Good explanation though!

Comment: **COOL TIP!** Use this logic with https://3widgets.com/ 

Answer (score 11):

RegExp does not seem to be the right tool here. If you have the year values already isolated surely a simple comparison would work :

```
if (+yr >= 1990 && +yr <= 2010)
```

The `+yr` converts the string to a number

Comment: if `+` converts into a number then use Number() or parseInt() instead. You write code for other humans and if you need to explain it it's most likely an inferior solution.

Answer (score 7):

For a range from 1950 to 2050 you may use the following regex:

```
^19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050$
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eQ9zK7)

Answer (score 4):

Regex:

```
/^(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d|2050)$/
```

Easier...

```
var year = parseInt(textField.value, 10);
if( year >= 1950 && year <= 2050 ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What happens with your RegEx if you have year `1960`, `1970`, etc..?

Comment: This regex will not work, only 1950-1959 and 2050-2059 are matched.

Answer (score 2):

```
(199[0-9]|200[0-9]|2010)
```

This will work in your 'example case'.

Helpful website: http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range

Answer (score 2):

Regex for Current Year(Dynamic) from 1995

```
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear().toString().split("");
var reg=new RegExp("^(199[5-9]|200[0-9]|[0-"+current_year[0]+"][0-"+current_year[1]+"][0-"+current_year[2]+"][0-"+current_year[3]+"])$");
reg.test("1995");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check for age between for example 18 or 70 I did it like this.
my solution was

```
function yearRange(year) {
  let now = new Date().getFullYear();
  let age = now - Number(year);
  if (age < 18 || age > 70) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex if you want to find a year in a film name for example.
Years b/n 1900 - 2029 and some symbols are allowed wrapping the year .-_+[(

```
(?<=(?:\s|\.|_|\-|\+|\(|\[))(?:19[2-9]|20[0-2])\d(?=\s|$|\.|_|\-|\+|\)|\])
```

check it out here
https://regex101.com/r/eQ9zK7/82

Note you can not start with year, because there is at least interval in front.
In the example first few lines are matching, because we have multiple lines in a single line they wont match.

1917.2019.1080p...
even if 1917 was in range it will mark only 2019