# PHP preg_replace for All Types of Year Formats (YYYY, YYYY-YYYY, YYYY - YYYY)

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-replace, pcre

Trying to just use preg_replace to make modifications in a string (adding an html line break) that contains year formats like `2018` `1950-2018` and `1950 - 2018`

```
$j = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}) - ([0-9]{4})/', '<br>* ${1} - ${2}</strong>', $j);
$j = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/', '<br>* ${1} - ${2}', $j);
$j = preg_replace('/\s+(19[5-9][0-9]|20(0[0-9]|10))\s+/', '<br>* ${1} </strong>', $j);
```

My preference would be the regex to be years `1950` - `2020`

The first two are working fine (although I was having trouble getting the range correct), but the last one is catching all instances

like:

```
* 2007
** 2008 - 2013
```

etc

Tried using `^` and `$` to denote the beginning and end.. but the third one always matches the first two.

How can I completely separate these year formats so I can uniquely change each one individually?

Sample Code:

```
<?php

$string = 'Detailed Applications: 2005-2006 Volkswagen | 2006 Volkswagen Golf 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS SOHC Naturally Aspirated | 2005 Volkswagen Beetle 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated | 2005 - 2006 Volkswagen Golf';

echo $string;

echo '<br><br>';

$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}) - ([0-9]{4})/', '<br /><strong>(YYYY - YYYY)* ${1} - ${2}</strong>', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/', '<br /><strong>(YYYY-YYYY)* ${1} - ${2}</strong>', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/(\d19[5-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])(?!\s?-)/', '<br /><strong>(YYYY)* ${1} </strong>', $string);

echo $string;
```

Outputs

```
Detailed Applications: 
(YYYY-YYYY)* 2005 - 
(YYYY)* 2006 Volkswagen | 
(YYYY)* 2006 Volkswagen Golf 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS SOHC Naturally Aspirated | 
(YYYY)* 2005 Volkswagen Beetle 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated | 
(YYYY - YYYY)* 2005 - 
(YYYY)* 2006
```

Sorry, really confused.

Basically what I'm doing is trying to loop it and just do a line-break (without exploding the string)... obviously with my regex it's outputting each on it's own line...

Trying to get an output like this

```
Detailed Applications: 
(YYYY-YYYY)* 2005 - 2006 Volkswagen | 
(YYYY)* 2006 Volkswagen Golf 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS SOHC Naturally Aspirated | 
(YYYY)* 2005 Volkswagen Beetle 2.0L 1984CC 121Cu. In. l4 GAS DOHC Naturally Aspirated | 
(YYYY - YYYY)* 2005 - 2006
```

But yeah.. here's the best I've gotten it

```
$j = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4}) - ([0-9]{4})/', '<br /><strong>* ${1} - ${2}</strong>', $j);
$j = preg_replace('/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})/', '<br /><strong>* ${1} - ${2}</strong>', $j);
$j = preg_replace('/(19[5-9][0-9]|20(0[0-9]|20))(?!\s?-)/', '<br /><strong>* ${1} </strong>', $j);
```

So here is an actual excerpt from my script

```
2007 Chevy Silverado Pickup new body style models 2008-2013 Chevy Silverado All Models 2014 Chevy Silverado 2500HD 3500HD 2007 GMC Sierra Pickup new body style models 2008-2013 GMC Sierra All Models 2014 GMC Sierra 2500HD 3500HD 2007-2013 Chevy Tahoe 2007-2013 Chevy Suburban 2007-2013 Chevy Avalanche 2007-2013 GMC Yukon Yukon XL Yukon Denali
```

Straight up all one line (posted the above sample script because this line does not include a `YYYY - YYYY` variation...)

It's outputting like this

```
* 2007 Chevy Silverado Pickup new body style models 
* 2008 - 2013 Chevy Silverado All Models 2014 Chevy Silverado 2500HD 3500HD 
* 2007 GMC Sierra Pickup new body style models 
* 2008 - 2013 GMC Sierra All Models 2014 GMC Sierra 2500HD 3500HD 
* 2007 - 2013 Chevy Tahoe 
* 2007 - 2013 Chevy Suburban 
* 2007 - 2013 Chevy Avalanche 
* 2007 - 2013 GMC Yukon Yukon XL Yukon Denali
```

All good except `* 2008 - 2013 Chevy Silverado All Models 2014 Chevy Silverado 2500HD 3500HD` the `2014` isn't breaking into a new line... and I also can't figure out how to do the year range yet (doh!) even referencing this [javascript regex validate years in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547710/javascript-regex-validate-years-in-range)

Comment: Ok. Any questions?

Comment: How can I completely separate these year formats so I can uniquely change each one individually?

Comment: So can you post a sample input string that covers all of the cases AND post your desired output for said sample string?

Comment: Do you need the strict validation in the third pattern?  You don't want the double-occurrence of `**` right?

Comment: Tim's answer helped but I'm having a hell of a time getting a lookbehind implemented... the negative lookahead works but it's still matching the input like `2008-
* 2013`

Comment: I'll try to post some code.. I'm still new at regex it is confusing the hell out of me :)

Comment: Okay, posted some code.... will also make an edit to show where I'm at in my actual script (can't actually post it since it's in a crazy loop with different variations coming from a json file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace_callback()` will let you validate/extract your targeted substrings and make conditional replacements in one pass.

- A `<br>` must be written before all year/year-ranges so long as it is not the very start of the string.  The first capture group is `\s*`, so it will capture zero or more white-space characters before your targeted year/year-range.  This element will always exist as `[1]` in the `$m` array.
- The second capture group is the first or only year value.  This is required to exist for the callback function to be implemented.  This is `[2]` in the `$m` array.
- As for the optional secondary year value, it must follow zero or more white-spaces then a hyphen then zero or more white-spaces. Because there are no capture groups to follow this capture group, php will only generate an element for this group if it is found -- `isset()` is used to check if `[3]` exists.
- Originally, I used `\b` to ensure that the year values were not substrings of larger digital substrings, but the format of your strings allows the use of white-space matching to confirm an accurate match.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6igNY)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8itmJf/2))

```
$string = "2007 Chevy Silverado Pickup new body style models 2008-2013 Chevy Silverado All Models 2014 Chevy Silverado 2500HD 3500HD 2007 GMC Sierra Pickup new body style models 2008 - 2013 GMC Sierra All Models 2014 GMC Sierra 2500HD 3500HD 2007-2013 Chevy Tahoe 2007-2013 Chevy Suburban 2007   -   2013 Chevy Avalanche 2007-2013 GMC Yukon Yukon XL Yukon Denali";

echo preg_replace_callback('~(\s*)(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d)(?:\s*-\s*(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d))?(?=\s)~', function($m) {
    //var_export($m);  // un-comment if you want to see each $m array
    //echo "\n---\n";
        return (strlen($m[1]) ? "\n" : "")
                . "<strong>*{$m[2]}"
                . (isset($m[3]) ? " - {$m[3]}" : "")
                . "</strong>";
    },
    $string);
```

Output:

```
<strong>*2007</strong> Chevy Silverado Pickup new body style models
<strong>*2008 - 2013</strong> Chevy Silverado All Models
<strong>*2014</strong> Chevy Silverado 2500HD 3500HD
<strong>*2007</strong> GMC Sierra Pickup new body style models
<strong>*2008 - 2013</strong> GMC Sierra All Models
<strong>*2014</strong> GMC Sierra 2500HD 3500HD
<strong>*2007 - 2013</strong> Chevy Tahoe
<strong>*2007 - 2013</strong> Chevy Suburban
<strong>*2007 - 2013</strong> Chevy Avalanche
<strong>*2007 - 2013</strong> GMC Yukon Yukon XL Yukon Denali
```

Comment: @Brian ...okay, I've fully cooked my solution now.  (first snippet was not professional grade)

Comment: Absolutely perfect response and output, can't thank you enough. RegEX and callback functions are two things I know I need to get down-- lots of really cool stuff you can do with them. Thanks again going to take the day to study your code and tune it to my scope.

Comment: badabing `~(\s+)?\b(19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d)(?:\s*-\s*(\d19[5-9]\d|20[0-4]\d))?\b~'` -- for the range I was trying to get at (I think :) still have to do some testing). The RegEX tester is a big help as well.. starting to make more sense.

Comment: I am happy to answer your follow up questions.

Comment: @Brian I wasn't completely happy with my solution/answer, so I've made a few refinements, incorporated your more restrictive year subpatterns, and explained my process a little better.  Let me know if I should clear anything up for you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify your replacement logic is to recognize that you want to add a `<br>` after every 4 digit year which is *not* followed by either a dash, or a space and a dash.  We can easily phrase this using a negative lookahead:

```
(\d{4})(?!\s?-)
```

Code sample:

```
$input = "that contains year formats like 2018 1950-2018 and 1950 - 2018";
echo preg_replace("/(\d{4})(?!\s?-)/", "$1<br>", $input);

that contains year formats like 2018<br> 1950-2018<br> and 1950 - 2018<br>
```

### Demo